# Why is the UITextField clipped when running "Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)"?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I'm new to iOS development and when I run the [code](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/swift/downloads/Start-Dev-iOS-Apps-03.zip) for [Connect the UI to Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1) I see the top of the text field is clipped:

[image]

I've checked the constraints, which all look fine (best I can tell).

**Update: Answer**

From my answer below: "Aha: The cause was that I had scaled the Simulator to 50%. There is no clipping at 75% or 100%."

**Update: Blended Layers screen shot**

Here's the screen shot with "Debug > Color Blended Layers" on (great tip!):

[image]

Comment: Your image shows no clipping.  You haven't told us about your constraints at all.

Comment: @nhgrif Sorry - What I meant was that if you look at the top of the text field, you'll see that the rounded rect border is missing.

Comment: @nhgrif Question: I looked for a textual 'export' in IB, specifically one that describes constraints, but no luck. Where would I find that so I can share? Or do folks take a screen shot of the relevant IB sections? Thank you.

Comment: Re: text version, I found the "Show the Version Editor" button (a misleading name?), which apparently shows the corresponding XML, including <constraints> tags. I'm not sure if that's what people generally share or not.

Answer (score 0):

Aha: The cause was that I had scaled the Simulator to 50%. There is no clipping at 75% or 100%.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the "meal name" label is place on top of the text field and overlaps it
use the Debug->"Color Blended Layers " option for simulator to see its positioning

[image]

Comment: That's what I first thought, but it looks fine in IB, and the constraints are OK. Awesome tip, BTW!

Comment: object position can be changed because of the Auto Layout behaviour,  so it's better check

Comment: Updated the question to show the app with the option enabled.